# flutter webview plugin open shrinked window

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

I am trying to open a window displaying a website and make the window smaller but still be able to see the full view. I can change the window size but when I do so the site doesnt adjust and its like I zoomed in.
Here is the code:

```
 flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(selectedUrl,

        // cookies
        // withLocalUrl: ,
        //withZoom: true,
        supportMultipleWindows: true,
        rect: new Rect.fromLTWH(
            0.0, 0.0, 150.0, 150.0),
        userAgent: iphoneXUA);
```

is there a way I can change the width to about 150 or 100 (same height) so its a square but still be able to see the full site (automatically zoom out to full view somehow)Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try launch webview plugin with "withOverviewMode: true" option:

```
   flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(selectedUrl,

    // cookies
    // withLocalUrl: ,
    //withZoom: true,
    supportMultipleWindows: true,
    withOverviewMode: true,
    rect: new Rect.fromLTWH(
        0.0, 0.0, 150.0, 150.0),
    userAgent: iphoneXUA);
```